# chart.js php live update

Tags: php, ajax, chart.js

Using Chart.JS (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/), I want to show live update results from database in page.
Can someone show me an example with AJAX how to get results and pass them in this code?

PHP:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM CMS_Stats ";
$result2 = $conn->query($query2);

while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
   $members[] = $row2['MembersOnline'];
   $guests[] = $row2['GuestsOnline'];
}
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: ['Now'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Members online",
            lineTension: 0.3,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,.90)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointRadius: 3,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: <?php echo json_encode($members) ?>,
        },
        {
            label: "Guests online",
            lineTension: 0.3,
            data: <?php echo json_encode($guests) ?>,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 185, 84,.90)",
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(211,84,0 ,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointRadius: 3,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211,84,0 ,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)"
        }
    ]
};

var option = {
    showLines: true
};
var myLineChart = Chart.Line(canvas,{
    data:data,
  options:option
});
```

Comment: Hello. Stackoverflow is here to help you, not to write code for you. Show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts with us. Nobody is going to write code for you. You should google for "AJAX examples", try to understand them and try it by yourself (its a really easy task...) - if you don't get it, come back here and ask again, but this time with your code you've written, even if it doesn't work. We'll help you find your mistakes and get your code running, but without any effort from you, nobody will help you.

Comment: I understand, but i dont know how to use ajax to integrate in my code.

Comment: As I said, try it. Its not that you don't know, its more that you don't try it to know. AJAX is really nothing complicated and with a little effort you'll learn it quite fast. Look a youtube tutorial or something. As you see, even if somebody answered your question here, its just a random code piece that you could find by yourself on google, so it won't help you at all if you don't understand the principe of AJAX. Try to do something with AJAX outside of your project, forget about chartjs for a moment. Just try to implement a really easy example, and you'll get into it :)

Comment: I appreciate your advice, thanks.

Comment: And as I said, feel free to come back here if you're stuck. If you show some effort, that you've tried it at least, you'll get much more help from the community. Thats how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need AJAX to run using interval:

```
setInterval(ajaxFunction(), 5000); // 5 sec
```

And in that function you have to call AJAX

```
function showHint(str) {

if (str.length == 0) { // case that doesn't call AJAX (can be discluded)
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {  // case that calls AJAX
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { //successfully getting answer
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText; // this.responseText is answer you get
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true); // your php file that works with recieved data and echoes answer
    xmlhttp.send();
}

}
```

AJAX part is just a random fragment from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp), if you are new to AJAX then just search for AJAX PHP